# Set every property type to not_analyzed for custom object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a custom object that I wish to store in ElasticSearch as its own type in an index, but I don't want any field in the object to be analyzed. How should I go about doing this?

I have been using the ElasticSearch NEST client but can also manually create the mapping if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options that will all work. Personally, I would go with either of the first two. If it's a daily index, then the second one is the better option.

- Define the mapping upfront and disable dynamic fields. This is by far the safest approach and it will help you to avoid mistakes, and it will prevent fields from being added afterward.

  ```
  {
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "mytype" : {
        "dynamic" : "strict",
        "properties" : {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- [Create an index template](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-templates.html#index-templates) that *also* disables dynamic fields, but allows you to continuously roll new indices with the same mapping(s).

  You can create tiered index templates so that more than one applies to any given index.

  ```
  {
    "template": "mytimedindex-*", 
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "mytype" : {
        "dynamic" : "strict",
        "properties" : {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- [Create a dynamic mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html) that allows new fields, but defaults all `string`s to `not_analyzed`:

  ```
  "dynamic_templates" : [ {
    "strings" : {
      "mapping" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "match" : "*",
      "match_mapping_type" : "string"
    }
  } ]
  ```

  This will allow you to dynamically add fields to the mapping.